# IFrame not working in xml version="1.0" + spring + jsp

Tags: spring, iframe, xhtml

The below mentioned tag is am uisng, and its not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<div xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
     xmlns:s="http://www.springframework.org/tags" xmlns:form="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" 
     xmlns:util="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/util" xmlns:input="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/input"
     xmlns:fmt="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"  
     version="2.0">
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
<jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<fieldset class="col-sm-12 bordure">
<form:form class="form-horizontal" modelAttribute="abcd" cssClass="form-horizontal" method="POST">
   <iframe src="demo_iframe.htm" name="iframe_a"></iframe>
   <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Header One </th>
            <th>Header Two </th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>Row One </td>
            <td>Row Two </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</form:form>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

I want to insert the table inside the IFrame. But table values not displaying while I put the code inside the IFrame. Only table values displaying outside the IFrame.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1):

Your presumption of how an `iframe` works is incorrect. *An iframe is used to embed another web page on an HTML document.* Optionally, you may put HTML inside the tag of the iframe. However, **any data inside the iframe tags will only be shown if the browser does not support iframes**. Therefore, you should keep the table outside of the iframe if you would like to see it on modern browsers.